# Calculating the limit of a Wasserstein distance of two SDE's

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations, optimal-control, optimal-transport, wasserstein

I am trying to prove that:
$\lim_{t \to \infty} W_2(\mu_t, \nu_t) = 0 $ where we have that $\mu_t = Law(X_t)$ and $\nu_t = Law(Z_t)$ with
$$dX_t = -h(X_t)dt + \sqrt(\frac{2}{\beta})dB_t$$
$$dZ_t = -h(Z_t)dt+\sqrt(\frac{2}{\beta})dB_t$$

I know that the Wasserstein distance in this case is given by:
$$W_2(\mu, \nu) := \iint|\theta-\theta'|^2\zeta(d\theta d\theta'))^\frac{1}{2}$$
However, I am not too sure where to go from here.

Comment: Are the SDEs on purpose identical or did you forget something?

Comment: No, they are suppose to be the same, just difference variables.

Comment: But then they are equal in law anyway and the statement is trivially true.

Comment: @Tobsn No, the initial states may be different.

Comment: Hm, true. But if the main point here are different initial conditions, then this should have been made clear in the question.

Comment: That’s somewhat trivial since one is $X_0$ and the other is $Z_0$ a.s.

Comment: Any assumptions on $h$?

Comment: Just that it’s a real number

Comment: In general this is not true. One can make some nasty examples like $h(x)=0$ if $x\leq 0$ and $h(x)=1$ if $x>0$. Now start with initial points $X_0$ and $Z_0$ such that $X_0\leq 0$ almost surely and $Z_0>1$ almost surely.

Comment: However, with some Lipschitz type condition on $h$, it is true. You can couple the two processes so that they are driven by the "same" Brownian motion. Then, you get something like $E(X_t-Z_t)^2\leq CE\left(\int_{0}^t(X_s-Z_s)ds\right)^2.$ Now interchange the square and integral (you will incur a cost of multiplicative factor of $t$) and use Gronwall type estimate!

Comment: Ah yes, it is Lipschitz so that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Strongly monotonic $h$ would also work, by almost the same argument.

Comment: @WhoKnowsWho How will this show that $W_2$ = $0$?

Comment: At which point of WhoKnowsWho's recipe from above, did you get stuck?

Comment: @J.North The above argument shows that $F_t:=E(X_t-Z_t)^2$ satisfies $F_t\leq \int_{0}^{t}F(s)ds$. Use this to show that $F_t\to 0$ as $t\to \infty.$ Now observe that $\W_2^2(\mu_t, \nu_t)\leq F_t.$